# Helper - undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function

**application_helper.rb**

```
def nl2br(s)
  s.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')
end
```

**View**

```
<%= nl2br(@event.rules).html_safe %>
```

**Error:**

> undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

At times the content can be `nil` so which is the best way to handle it?

When I add `unless s.nil?` in the function I get `html_safe undefined method error`.

Comment: this will work : `<%= nl2br(@event.rules.to_s).html_safe %>` you dont need to change any thing in method or may be if you dont want to append `.to_s` for everything when you are calling the method. just add `to_s` here `s.to_s.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Updated 2019)

With modern Ruby (2.3+), you can use the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/):

```
def nl2br(s)
  s&.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')
end
```

If `s` is nil, `s&.gsub` will fall back to nil, which will then output as empty string.

---

(Original answer from 2015)

Simple trick, just use an OR to setup a default:

```
def nl2br(s)
  (s||'').gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')
end
```

Alternatively, since `nil.to_s` evaluates to an empty string, you can do:

```
def nl2br(s)
  s.to_s.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')
end
```